# Proximity Prompt does not have errors but does not work

Tags: lua, roblox, luau

This may seem very easy but I am a beginner in scripting Roblox. There are no errors but the proximity prompt wasn't working. I tried to use the print function to test but it did not print either. Here is the code! (Also don't mind anything else)

```
local cost = 500
local serverscriptstorage = game.ServerScriptService
local petMoudle = require(game.ServerScriptService:WaitForChild("BasicEggModule"))
local prompt = workspace["Egg Holder"].Part.ProximityPrompt


prompt.Triggered:Connect(function (player)
    print("hi")
    if player.leaderstats.Cash.Value >= cost then
        player.leaderstats.Cash.Value = player.leaderstats.Cash.Value - cost
        local pet = petMoudle.chooseRandomPet()
        local petval = Instance.new("StringValue")
        petval.Name = pet.Name
        petval.Parent = player.PetInventory
        print(pet.Name.." selected")
        game.ReplicatedStorage.HatchEgg:FireClient(player, pet)
    end
end)
```

Thank you so much! Also, the script is in a folder in ServerScriptService.

Comment: Put a print after the variable declarations and another at the very end of the script, see if it is hitting them. It's possible that something is blocking the code execution, like the require statement or the waitforchild calls. Then putting it the prompt variable to make sure you found the right one. Are there multiple product prompts? Are you interacting with the correct one?

Comment: @Kylaaa Both prints did not work. What should I do?

Comment: Just a sanity check, this is a Script and not a LocalScript right? Try putting a print on the very first line. My guess right now would be that the PetModule is taking a long time to load for some reason.

Comment: I found out what the problem was! In the third line, it had to beServerScriptService.Folder:WaitForChild(). Thanks for trying to helping me tough!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was! In the third line.
It had to be
`ServerScriptService.Folder:WaitForChild()`.

The Folder wasn't there.